# tkinter listbox get(ACTIVE) method

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

I was trying to make the currently selected `Listbox` item to be printed out. For example, when I select item "one", it should print out "one" and when I select item "two", it should print out "two" etc. The following is what I have tried.

```
from Tkinter import*
root=Tk()
sizex = 600
sizey = 400
posx  = 40
posy  = 20
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))
itemsforlistbox=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']

def CurSelet(evt):
    value=str((mylistbox.get(ACTIVE)))
    print value

mylistbox=Listbox(root,width=60,height=10,font=('times',13))
mylistbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',CurSelet)
mylistbox.place(x=32,y=90)

for items in itemsforlistbox:
    mylistbox.insert(END,items)
root.mainloop()
```

My problem is whenever I selected an item in the listbox, it is actually printing out the previously selected item.For example, the moment I select the item "two" in the list, it is printing out "one". To make things more clear,please see the following

1. I selected the item "one", it printed out "one"
2. I selected the item "two", it print out "one" again
3. I selected the item "three", it print out "two" and so on...

Am I missing something? or did I misunderstand the way the `get(ACTIVE)` works?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

An item becomes active after you click on it—which means after your `ListboxSelect` method returns. So, you're printing out whatever was active *before* this click (meaning, generally, what you clicked *last time*).

Also, given that you refer to "selected" numerous times, I think what you want is the *selected* value(s), not the *active* one, so you should be asking for that.

For a listbox with `selectmode=SINGLE` or `BROWSE` (the default, what you have) listbox, you can fix both of these trivially. Just change this:

```
mylistbox.get(ACTIVE)
```

to:

```
mylistbox.get(mylistbox.curselection())
```

If you need to handle `MULTIPLE` or `EXTENDED`, then of course there are anywhere from 0 to 7 selections instead of exactly 1, so you need to do something like:

```
values = [mylistbox.get(idx) for idx in mylistbox.curselection()]
print ', '.join(values)
```

While we're at it, I'm not sure why you were doing `str((mylistbox.get(ACTIVE)))`, or even `str(mylistbox.get(ACTIVE))`. The result of `mylistbox.get` with a single index is going to be a string, the same one you inserted.

Comment: thanks a lot.. you are right. i misunderstood the word "active" means. and thanks for pointing out about the string. It was my mistake.

Comment: @ChrisAung: It's hard to blame you for not knowing. Looking them over, the docs don't exactly explain what active means, and don't even hint that this is a "item becoming active" type event rather than an "item became active" one. The TkInter docs sometimes assume you already know Tcl/Tk, and they're even worse for anything added after Tk 8.0, so you often need to go read the [Tk man pages](http://www.tcl.tk/man/) or other documentation, or just do a lot of experimenting.

Comment: i am a total beginner.. so i have no idea what Tcl/Tk means.. what is the main difference between Tkinter and Tcl/Tk?

Comment: @ChrisAung: Briefly: Tk is the built-in GUI for the scripting language Tcl. Tkinter, the built-in GUI for Python, is a set of wrappers around Tcl/Tk, written in a combination of Python and Tcl. That's why the [Tkinter docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) have links to the [Tcl/Tk manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/) and various other related docs.

Comment: @abarnert I am getting ```_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number```

Comment: .get(ANCHOR) should be a more correct answer than this.

Answer (score 13):

This seems to work for me:

```
mylistbox.get(ANCHOR)
```

Based on your code, it will print out the current item.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this, it doesn't require the list box. So if you have multiple list boxes it will retrieve the value from any

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
sizex = 600
sizey = 400
posx  = 40
posy  = 20
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))
itemsforlistbox=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']

def CurSelet(event):
    widget = event.widget
    selection=widget.curselection()
    picked = widget.get(selection[1])
    print(picked)

mylistbox=Listbox(root,width=60,height=10,font=('times',13))
mylistbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',CurSelet)
mylistbox.place(x=32,y=90)

for items in itemsforlistbox:
    mylistbox.insert(END,items)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

as stated by user1576772 the correct answer should be :

```
mylistbox.get(ANCHOR)
```

The Problem with `curselection()` is it returns the whole list currently selected each time.

consider a situation where you scroll through a Listbox and want always to get the last selected item forward or backward (not the last item in highlighted list , the last item pressed on by user )! `curselection()` will give you all the currently selected items which is helpful but you will never know which item was selected last !

Answer (score -1):

The line `picked = widget.get(selection[1])` should be `picked = widget.get(selection[0])`.

Otherwise, there will be an "index out of range" error.