# displaying a selection from a listbox in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Just a snippet, but I'm trying to display the factor of a multiplication factor set in a listbox.  I am displaying the list of factors using FirstFactor and SecondFactor, hence the while loop.  However, the "get" from the selection displays in a message box the last factor in the times table instead of the one selected. Any suggestions?

```
def addListItems(self):
        global firstFactor
        firstFactor = 7
        global secondFactor
        secondFactor = 1
        
        while (secondFactor < 13):
            global mult
            mult = ("%d X %d" %(firstFactor, secondFactor))
            self.listbox.insert(END,mult)
            secondFactor += 1
            

    def onClickSubmit(self):
        selection = self.listbox.curselection()
        index = int(selection[0])
        answer = (firstFactor*secondFactor)
        messagebox.showinfo(title=mult, message=answer)
```

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672552/python-tkinter-listbox-get-active-method

Comment: mylistbox.get(ANCHOR)

Comment: You are using the global variables `firstFactor` and `secondFactor` which are set to the final values (7 and 12 respectively) after the while loop.  You should extract the two values from the selected item of the listbox instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
selected = self.listbox.get(self.listbox.curselection())
print(selected)
```

here , selected is a variable that satisfies the current selected item in a listbox.
the "get"method helps to capture some content, whereas the "curselection()" method is, as its name says, the current selected item