# Problem in associating the elements of a Listbox with some values

Tags: python, tkinter

I am Working with the Listboxes in Python. I have inserted a list of books in the Listbox. But I wish to show the details of these books when I click the book names in the Listbox. I have tried using the if statement but it is not working.Here is the code

```
  def det():
    for val in my_listbox:
        if val==b1:
            print('It’s impossible to talk about mystery novels without immediately thinking of the legendary Agatha Christie. Amongst all of her works, none has a story quite as impeccably crafted as And Then There Were None, which explains why it is the best selling mystery book of all time.' )
```

where b1 is the first book in the listbox. Please suggest me some command which I can use.

Comment: You could be intressted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40448590/13629335

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution -- assuming that each value in the listbox is unique -- is to associate a dictionary or database row with the listbox items. Then it becomes a trivial matter to show the data associated with the selection.

For example, given a data structure like this:

```
data = {
    "Treasure Island": {"author": "Robert Louis Stevenson"},
    "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer": {"author": "Mark Twain"},
}
```

... and given that the book titles are inserted into the listbox, the following code can be used to update a label named `detail` with the author of the selected book:

```
def show_detail(event=None):
    selection = listbox.curselection()
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        title = listbox.get(index)
        author = data[title]["author"]
        detail.configure(text=f"Author: {author}")
...
listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", show_detail)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a causal python or tkinter?
If it is tkinter the print() is only work in background (on the black screen)
U can use Label()

```
def det():
    for val in my_listbox:
        if val==b1:
            Label(text='It’s impossible to talk about mystery novels without immediately thinking of the legendary Agatha Christie. Amongst all of her works, none has a story quite as impeccably crafted as And Then There Were None, which explains why it is the best selling mystery book of all time.' ).pack()
```