# Is there a way to save the result of a button's command of tkinter with the def written in a module?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, return

I'm barely new in Python, so forgive me if my codes aren't written in a correct 'pythonic way'...
I want to save the user's choice from a listbox. The function is defined in the BES_library module (I need the function to stay here in the module and not in the script!):

```
##BES_library
def quit(root, listbox, choice):
    #get the user's choice
    choice = listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
    print(choice)

    #quit the ListBox
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()   

    return choice
```

And this is my script:

```
import tkinter           as tk
import BES_library       as BES_lib

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SheetsNames = ['Foglio1', 'Foglio2', 'Foglio3']
    SheetName = 'lalala'
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Select the worksheet to be opened")
    listbox = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode= 'single')
    for item in SheetsNames:
       listbox.insert("end", item)
       listbox.pack()
    button = tk.Button(root, text='Select', command= lambda: BES_lib.quit(root, listbox, SheetName) ) 
    button.pack()
    root.geometry("450x300+120+120")
    root.mainloop()

    print(SheetName)

#now I want to work with the SheetName chosen by the user
```

The user is supposed to select one of the options from the listbox and click the 'Select' button. Upon clicking the button, I want to attribute his choice to a variable as a string and quit the listbox.

The question is, how can I use what the user entered? The button doesn't save the return value of functions.

I tried also this code, but nothing seems to be changed:

```
import tkinter           as tk
import BES_library       as BES_lib

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SheetsNames = ['Foglio1', 'Foglio2', 'Foglio3']
        
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Select the worksheet to be opened")

    SheetName = tk.StringVar()

    listbox = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode= 'single')
    for item in SheetsNames:
       listbox.insert("end", item)
       listbox.pack()
    button = tk.Button(root, text='Select', command= lambda: BES_lib.quit(root, listbox, SheetName) ) 
    button.pack()
    root.geometry("450x300+120+120")
    root.mainloop()

    print(SheetName.get())

 #now I want to work with the SheetName chosen by the user
```

Comment: are you aware of listbox.get('ANCHOR') ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40448590/13629335

Comment: To destroy a widget you can youse `pack_forget()` or `place_forget()` depending on the manager you used

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that eliminates the need to use the `quit` method, at all. Your quit method didn't make sense, anyway. It claims to remove the `listbox` but it destroys the entire `root` of the app. You also have a misconception ~ you are trying to print something after calling `root.mainloop`. Nothing you do after `root.mainloop` is ever going to get hit. `root.mainloop` needs to be the last line of your program.

Using my method, The `listbox` and `button` are placed in a frame. Every time a user clicks on the `listbox` it stores the selection. Calling `sheetframe.pack()` shows the selection frame and clicking `select` unpacks/hides it. In this way, `select` isn't selecting anything. The selection was already recorded as soon as a `listbox` item was clicked.

```
import tkinter as tk

#init root
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Select the worksheet to be opened")
root.geometry("450x300+120+120")

#init vars
sheetlist  = ['Foglio1', 'Foglio2', 'Foglio3']
sheetname  = 'lalala'

#container for listbox and button
sheetframe = tk.Frame(root)

listbox    = tk.Listbox(sheetframe, selectmode='single', listvariable=tk.StringVar(value=sheetlist))
listbox.pack()

#unpack/hide sheetframe on click
tk.Button(sheetframe, text='Select', command=sheetframe.pack_forget).pack()

#store a listbox selection a soon as it is clicked    
def selection(event):
    global sheetname
    sheetname = listbox.get('anchor')
    print(f'{sheetname} selected')

#bind on ButtonRelease so anchor is definitely set
listbox.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', selection)

#show sheetframe
sheetframe.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Especially I learned how to create a listbox without using a for-cycle!
But unfortunately you don't answer to my question... it is mandatory that my function ('quit', or even your 'selection') is defined in a module and not in the script (actually must be generic for other scripts). My problem is that in the script I cannot obtain a variable with the string chosen: actually I don't need to print it but I wanna save it to use it later...

Comment: @user14171495 ~ of course that isn't mandatory. It doesn't even make sense to be that way, but if you must ~ go stick it in a module and use it from there. I answered more questions than you asked. My answer to the module part of your question is "Don't stick it in a module. Keep it with the widget that uses it."

Comment: Yes, absolutely! You answered more questions than I asked (and for this I am very grateful to you)! And of course, in general, define a function in a module isn't mandatory... but in this case, the instruction I received is this... don't ask me why... So I'd tried to stick your function in a module but it still don't fix my problem. So my question now is: is there a way to do that or not? Can you help me?