# how can i get the inserted optionmenu value of a selected object in list from database in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

when i click a row of my list box i want to show value in my drop down list.

```
def callback(selection):
    selected = selection
    return selected

edumenu=StringVar()
eduvalue=StringVar()
edumenu=OptionMenu(window, eduvalue, "red", "blue", "green",command=callback)
edumenu.grid(row=1,column=4)
eduvalue.set("red")


def get_selected_row(event):
    global selected_data
        eduvalue.set(callback(edumenu))

list1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", get_selected_row)
```

it returns the *data type of value* in option menu not **text value**

Comment: Because it is ```edumenu.get()```. To get a value of the ```StringVar```, you need to call the ```.get()``` method

Comment: i have done what you just said and it's showing me this error : AttributeError: 'OptionMenu' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Because you again defined edumenu as an option menu after stringvar. Change the name of the variable for option menu

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672552/tkinter-listbox-getactive-method refer to this and set that value as eduvalue

Comment: What ia the point of this line `edumenu=StringVar()`? You almost immediately reassign the same variable to sth else. Also per PEP8 You should have space between operators, in this case: `edumenu = StringVar()`, exception would be if it were a keyword argument

Comment: @Sujay  i have deleted edumenu but it stills returns type of option menu except the value. how can i use .get() in option menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve your problem.

```
from tkinter import *
  
  
# create a root window.
top = Tk()
  
# create listbox object
listbox = Listbox(top, height = 10, 
                  width = 15, 
                  )
  
# Define the size of the window.
top.geometry("300x250")  
  
# Define a label for the list.  
label = Label(top, text = " FOOD ITEMS") 
  
# insert elements by their
# index and names.
listbox.insert(1, "Nachos")
listbox.insert(2, "Sandwich")
listbox.insert(3, "Burger")
listbox.insert(4, "Pizza")
listbox.insert(5, "Burrito")
  
# pack the widgets
label.pack()
listbox.pack()
def callback(selection):
    selected = selection
    return selected

edumenu=StringVar()
eduvalue=StringVar()
edumenu2=OptionMenu(top, eduvalue, "red", "blue", "green",command=callback)
edumenu2.pack()
eduvalue.set("red")


def get_selected_row(event):
    global selected_data
    eduvalue.set(callback(listbox.get(listbox.curselection())))

listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", get_selected_row)
  
# Display untill User 
# exits themselves.
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thx, it's worked, But there was a little problem that when I receive data from **database**, I have to call the required object after _get()_ like this:  `listbox.get(...)[2]` and now it's working fine.