# Match sorting data from the list given in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am working on a project, where there is suggestion of data

I had seen many methods online, but none of them came handy, I worked a little bit and sort by little methods, this auto suggestion is working fine but clumsy, so can any one please say how to optimize the data

```
# importing only  those functions
# which are needed
from tkinter import *

# creating tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('Sample')
root.geometry('400x400')

# this assigns the name value
name = StringVar()

# this is list values
list_box_data = ['Apple', "Ball", "Cat"]

name_lab = Label(root, width=15, text="Name")
name_lab.place(x=50, y=100)

Entry_box = Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=name)
Entry_box.place(x=150, y=100)

submit_but = Button(root, width=12, text='Print')
submit_but.place(x=150, y=150)

# there are listbox creation
list_box = Listbox(root, height=10, width=15)


def search_name(event):
    """when a key was pressed in entry box this method is called"""
    # list_box is placed
    list_box.place(x=150, y=120)

    # assigning the methods to listbox
    list_box.bind('<Leave>', curse_out)
    list_box.bind('<Double-1>', items_selected)
    list_box.bind('<Return>', items_selected)

    # this checks the list is existed or not
    if list_box_data is not None:
        # this checks for the match in phone numbers list and assigned as matched list
        match = [i for i in list_box_data if name.get() in i]

        # for inserting new data delete the old data
        list_box.delete(0, END)

        # this for add data to the listbox
        for c in match:
            list_box.insert(END, c)

        # if no existing match then the list box closes
        if not match:
            curse_out(None)

    # if the entry box is empty then it close the list box
    if name.get() == "":
        curse_out(None)


def items_selected(event):
    """when the no is selected from list box it aligned to
    the name and gives the data"""

    # this when selected the data to following happens
    for i in list_box.curselection():
        name_data = list_box.get(i)
        name.set(name_data)
        curse_out(None)


def print_text():
    print(name.get())


def curse_out(event):
    """this is the command whey the cursor is out form box it closes"""
    try:
        list_box.place_forget()
    except BaseException:
        pass


submit_but.config(command=print_text)
Entry_box.bind("<KeyRelease>", search_name)
Entry_box.bind("<Down>", lambda event: list_box.focus_set())

root.mainloop()
```

The code is working good in but with little issues.

1. when the list box is open and selecting on other widgeds the box is open always, its not closing, so can we (focus in) entry box and list box at a time
2. every time I want to have this entry and suggestion the whole code should be repeated again and again, can we convert it into class method by passing (list and entry) only so its wont be clumsy

Comment: The second issue you mentioned is not necessarily an issue but something pending to do perhaps, as your code currently does not seem to be defining any classes, so its not as if you have an issue in an existing object oriented part of your code right?

Answer (score 0):

1. For your first issue, which seems to be regarding the ability to
   focus multiple tkinter widgets, at once, it is not possible. The
   current implementation being used by you is the best you can do i.e.
   bind the down arrow key to a function that brings focus to the
   listbox.

   ```
   Entry_box.bind("<Down>", lambda event: list_box.focus_set())
   ```

   In addition to this, you can also bind the up arrow key of the
   listbox to a function that checks if the first item is currently
   selected, if so it switches focus to the Entry widget.

   ```
   def set_entry_focus(event) :
       if list_box.curselection()[0] == 0 : Entry_box.focus_set()
       return
   list_box.bind("<Up>", set_entry_focus)
   ```

   **NOTE:** Here, we use the curselection method of the tkinter listbox widget, to [get the index of all the currently selected items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672552/tkinter-listbox-getactive-method)
   in the form of a tuple, we then fetch the 0th index of that assuming
   that the listbox has been set to only select one item at a time.
2. The second issue you mentioned is not necessarily an issue but
   something pending to do perhaps, as your code currently does not
   seem to be defining any classes. If given a code to work with, and a
   problem to fix, I will be more than happy to attach the solution
   later in the EDIT section of this answer.

The full code with the entry focus addition will become -:

```
# importing only  those functions
# which are needed
from tkinter import *

# creating tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('Sample')
root.geometry('400x400')

# this assigns the name value
name = StringVar()

# this is list values
list_box_data = ['Apple', "Ball", "Cat"]

name_lab = Label(root, width=15, text="Name")
name_lab.place(x=50, y=100)

Entry_box = Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=name)
Entry_box.place(x=150, y=100)

submit_but = Button(root, width=12, text='Print')
submit_but.place(x=150, y=150)

# there are listbox creation
list_box = Listbox(root, height=10, width=15)


def search_name(event):
    """when a key was pressed in entry box this method is called"""
    # list_box is placed
    list_box.place(x=150, y=120)

    # assigning the methods to listbox
    list_box.bind('<Leave>', curse_out)
    list_box.bind('<Double-1>', items_selected)
    list_box.bind('<Return>', items_selected)

    # this checks the list is existed or not
    if list_box_data is not None:
        # this checks for the match in phone numbers list and assigned as matched list
        match = [i for i in list_box_data if name.get() in i]

        # for inserting new data delete the old data
        list_box.delete(0, END)

        # this for add data to the listbox
        for c in match:
            list_box.insert(END, c)

        # if no existing match then the list box closes
        if not match:
            curse_out(None)

    # if the entry box is empty then it close the list box
    if name.get() == "":
        curse_out(None)


def items_selected(event):
    """when the no is selected from list box it aligned to
    the name and gives the data"""

    # this when selected the data to following happens
    for i in list_box.curselection():
        name_data = list_box.get(i)
        name.set(name_data)
        curse_out(None)


def print_text():
    print(name.get())


def curse_out(event):
    """this is the command whey the cursor is out form box it closes"""
    try:
        list_box.place_forget()
    except BaseException:
        pass

def set_entry_focus(event) :
    if list_box.curselection()[0] == 0 : Entry_box.focus_set()
    return

submit_but.config(command=print_text)
Entry_box.bind("<KeyRelease>", search_name)
Entry_box.bind("<Down>", lambda event: list_box.focus_set())
list_box.bind("<Up>", set_entry_focus)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Also, I noticed that the autocomplete checker provided in the OP, was not working as probably intended. Instead of matching the entry text with the first few characters of the list item, it matched the character at entry index 1 to the list items. It also was matching in a case sensitive manner.

**NOTE:** Incase any of these features of the autocompleter were intended, then the above provided full code still contains the approach previously used and this section is keeping in mind the ability of this answer to help any future visitors.

I have thus also tweaked it a little bit to work better -:

```
## NOW IT CHECKS THE FIRST N LETTERS OF EACH LIST ITEM, WHERE N IS THE LENGTH
## OF THE TEXT TYPED IN THE ENTRY, IT ALSO NOW DOES NOT DEPEND ON CAPS.
match = [i for i in list_box_data if name.get() in i[ : len(name.get())].lower()]
```

The full search_name function after the change would look like this -:

```
def search_name(event):
    """when a key was pressed in entry box this method is called"""
    # list_box is placed
    list_box.place(x=150, y=120)

    # assigning the methods to listbox
    list_box.bind('<Leave>', curse_out)
    list_box.bind('<Double-1>', items_selected)
    list_box.bind('<Return>', items_selected)

    # this checks the list is existed or not
    if list_box_data is not None:
        # this checks for the match in phone numbers list and assigned as matched list
        ## NOW IT CHECKS THE FIRST N LETTERS OF EACH LIST ITEM, WHERE N IS THE LENGTH
        ## OF THE TEXT TYPED IN THE ENTRY, IT ALSO NOW DOES NOT DEPEND ON CAPS.
        match = [i for i in list_box_data if name.get() in i[ : len(name.get())].lower()]

        # for inserting new data delete the old data
        list_box.delete(0, END)

        # this for add data to the listbox
        for c in match:
            list_box.insert(END, c)

        # if no existing match then the list box closes
        if not match:
            curse_out(None)

    # if the entry box is empty then it close the list box
    if name.get() == "":
        curse_out(None)
```